# Pass variable into catch - Java

Tags: java, android, variables, try-catch

I'm making an app in Android Studio that lets you keep track of how many times you've been on a roller coaster and works out how much g force you've been through etc.

I want the `rideCount` variable to save on exit so I got it to write to a file. Then when that activity starts, it will read that file and put it into the `rideCount` variable. Because it writes on exit, there's nothing in the file at first.

What I want it to do when that happens is set `rideCount` to `0` and call up the method that sets everything else up, but I can't seem to pass the `rideCount` variable to the catch bit. Can anyone help?

Thank in advance.

```
File file = new File("AltonAirCount.txt");

    try{
        Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
        int rideCountFile = input.nextInt();
        final int[] rideCount = {rideCountFile};
        onCreate2(rideCount);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex){
       //I want it to set rideCount to 0 here
      //I want it to call up onCreate2 and pass rideCount to it
    }}
```

.

```
    public void onBackPressed(int[] rideCount, File file) {

    try {
        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(file);
        output.println(rideCount);
        output.close();

    } catch (IOException ex) {


    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`rideCountFile` must be declare before the try block in order to be accessible by the catch block.

```
int rideCountFile;
try{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
    rideCountFile = input.nextInt();
    final int[] rideCount = {rideCountFile};
    onCreate2(rideCount);
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex){
    rideCountFile = 0;
    // call onCreate2 again if you wish
    final int[] rideCount = {rideCountFile};
    onCreate2(rideCount);
}
```

Of course, unless you need to use the `rideCountFile` in some later code you didn't include, you don't need it at all in the catch block, so the code can be simplified to :

```
try{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
    int rideCountFile = input.nextInt();
    final int[] rideCount = {rideCountFile};
    onCreate2(rideCount);
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex){
    onCreate2(new int[] {0});
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It fixed what was broken before however when I exit and reload the app, the variable resets to 0. I've added the part of the code that writes the file to my initial post in case it is that part that is the problem.